# Why aren't cookies being set when I use a Route::domain()->group()?

Tags: php, laravel

I just moved my routes from `mydomain.com` to `*.mydomain.com` and now sessions/cookies are not working as I intended (Cant save session data past a page reload and cookies are not being set). I haven't configured anything past the default Laravel configuration.

Here are my routes.

```
$storefrontDomain = '{subdomain}.' . parse_url(config('app.url'), PHP_URL_HOST);

Route::domain($storefrontDomain)->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', [StorefrontController::class, 'showHomePage'])
        ->name('storefront.homepage.get');

    Route::get('/login', [StorefrontController::class, 'showLoginPage'])
        ->name('storefront.login.get');

    Route::get('/logout', [StorefrontController::class, 'logout'])
        ->name('storefront.logout.get');

    Route::get('/pages/{page_slug}', [StorefrontController::class, 'showPage'])
        ->name('storefront.page.get');

    Route::get('/{category_slug}', [StorefrontController::class, 'showCategoryPage'])
        ->name('storefront.category.get');
});
```

I'd like cookies/sessions to be unique across each of the subdomains, what do I have to do to achieve this?

Comment: Check [this](https://gist.github.com/JacobBennett/15558410de2a394373ac) tip, might help you. You will also need to check `config/session.php` file (change 'domain' to `.mydomain.com` -> however that will share cookies across all subdomains, if you want to create subdomain-specific cookies, you have to build custom logic (check [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#attaching-cookies-to-responses))

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I missed a return statement in one of my methods.

Answer (score 0):

Go to config\session.php

and fix the config key 'domain' and make sure you use it across all subdomains.

Comment: For my development environment I'm using SESSION_DOMAIN=".localhost" but it isn't working, no cookies are being set on any subdomain.